# Store CLLocationCoordinate2D in CoreData as Transformable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I want to store a CLLocationCoordinate2D Object in CoreData. I've created an attribute in my entity called `location` with type `Transformable`. I've created a subclass of NSManagedObject which looks like this:

```
extension Task {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Task> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Task>(entityName: "Task");
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D

}
```

But when I want to set the attribute it throws an error

```
let task = Task(context: context)
task.name =  "Hello"
task.location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(10), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(12))
```

Here the error message:

```
2016-12-24 11:50:27.425833 CoreDataTodo[839:273413] [error] error: Property 'setLocation:' is a scalar type on class 'Task' that does not match its Entity's property's scalar type.  Dynamically generated accessors do not support implicit type coercion.  Cannot generate a setter method for it.
CoreData: error: Property 'setLocation:' is a scalar type on class 'Task' that does not match its Entity's property's scalar type.  Dynamically generated accessors do not support implicit type coercion.  Cannot generate a setter method for it.
2016-12-24 11:50:27.426143 CoreDataTodo[839:273413] -[Task setLocation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1766eca0
2016-12-24 11:50:27.426780 CoreDataTodo[839:273413] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Task setLocation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1766eca0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c5a0df7 0x1b803077 0x1c5a6505 0x1c5a4579 0x1c4c93d8 0x4b8cc 0x4bd60 0x21681ee5 0x21681e73 0x2166bf97 0x2168179b 0x216812e7 0x2167bee7 0x2164ccf5 0x21de898d 0x21de25d3 0x1c55c71b 0x1c55c225 0x1c55a4fb 0x1c4a9533 0x1c4a9341 0x1dc80bfd 0x216b7e27 0x216b2551 0x4f520 0x1bc7350b)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a transformable attribute, you need one of the following:

- An Attribute type that conforms to `NSCoding`. `CLLocationCoordinate2D` does not, in part because only classes can conform. This is what those error messages are trying to explain.
- A custom subclass of `NSValueTransformer` that can convert between the data type and `NSData`.

You could use the second option. But it'd be easier to store the latitude and longitude values separately as their own attributes. Then add a convenience method to your subclass that combines them and returns a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

Comment: Thanks I think I will do it by storing latitude and longitude seperatly. But could you give an example code how to do the `NSValueTransformer` subclass. I would really like to know how that works.

Comment: @Codey did you get this working? If so, can you post an example?

Comment: Yes I also thought that saving latitude and longitude separately was the best idea. But I was curious how it would work with the `NSValueTransformer`. I would appreciate it if you gave an example for that.