# Save Map Coordinates in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, mapkit

There is no attribute type for CoreData as CLLocation. How can I store the coordinate in the CoreData entity's attribute?

I have tried to define that in another swift file which has the same name as the CoreData Model entity. However, it complains duplicated declaration.

How can I store the CLLocation as CoreData entity's attribute then?

Comment: If you are talking just about the coordinate (`lat` and `lng`) either declare two Core Data Double attributes or a computed property to convert `lat` and `lng` from and to JSON and on the Core Data side save a string.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312614/store-cllocationcoordinate2d-in-coredata-as-transformable/41317858#41317858